# Substrate node template make: *** [Makefile:19: build] Error 101

Tags: linux, rust, webassembly, substrate

Currently running `rustc 1.49.0 (e1884a8e3 2020-12-29)` and nightly `rustc 1.51.0-nightly (a2f8f6281 2021-01-27)` on Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I overcome this error 101?

Ran `make init` which returned positive results after getting rust nightly properly installed.

```
./scripts/init.sh
*** Initializing WASM build environment
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.51.0-nightly (a2f8f6281 2021-01-27)

info: checking for self-updates
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-2020-10-05-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2020-10-05, rust version 1.49.0-nightly (beb5ae474 2020-10-04)
info: downloading component 'cargo'
info: downloading component 'clippy'
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
 13.3 MiB /  13.3 MiB (100 %)   5.7 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
 22.1 MiB /  22.1 MiB (100 %)   4.8 MiB/s in  5s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustc'
 54.9 MiB /  54.9 MiB (100 %)   4.7 MiB/s in 12s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: using up to 500.0 MiB of RAM to unpack components
info: installing component 'clippy'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
 13.3 MiB /  13.3 MiB (100 %)   3.3 MiB/s in  4s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rust-std'
 22.1 MiB /  22.1 MiB (100 %)   9.6 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rustc'
 54.9 MiB /  54.9 MiB (100 %)  10.7 MiB/s in  5s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rustfmt'

  nightly-2020-10-05-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu installed - rustc 1.49.0-nightly (beb5ae474 2020-10-04)

info: checking for self-updates
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.49.0 (e1884a8e3 2020-12-29)

info: checking for self-updates
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-unknown-unknown' is up to date
info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
info: installing component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
info: using up to 500.0 MiB of RAM to unpack components
 13.1 MiB /  13.1 MiB (100 %)  10.4 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
```

Ran `make build` which caused the above error. Here are the results

```
   Compiling libc v0.2.73
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.19
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.1
   Compiling syn v1.0.36
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling autocfg v1.0.0
   Compiling log v0.4.11
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.114
   Compiling serde v1.0.114
   Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
   Compiling byteorder v1.3.4
   Compiling smallvec v1.4.1
   Compiling memchr v2.3.3
   Compiling getrandom v0.1.14
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling typenum v1.12.0
   Compiling futures v0.1.29
   Compiling either v1.6.1
   Compiling slab v0.4.2
   Compiling futures-core v0.3.5
   Compiling proc-macro-hack v0.5.18
   Compiling futures-sink v0.3.5
   Compiling maybe-uninit v2.0.0
   Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
   Compiling pin-project-internal v0.4.23
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.8
   Compiling proc-macro-nested v0.1.6
   Compiling futures-io v0.3.5
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.2.3
   Compiling byte-tools v0.3.1
   Compiling arrayvec v0.5.1
   Compiling ahash v0.3.8
   Compiling fake-simd v0.1.2
   Compiling subtle v2.2.3
   Compiling crunchy v0.2.2
   Compiling static_assertions v1.1.0
   Compiling tinyvec v0.3.3
   Compiling subtle v1.0.0
   Compiling itoa v0.4.6
   Compiling arrayref v0.3.6
   Compiling keccak v0.1.0
   Compiling constant_time_eq v0.1.5
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.6.18
   Compiling crc32fast v1.2.0
   Compiling signature v1.1.0
   Compiling libm v0.2.1
   Compiling adler v0.2.3
   Compiling ryu v1.0.5
   Compiling serde_json v1.0.57
   Compiling radium v0.3.0
   Compiling byte-slice-cast v0.3.5
   Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
   Compiling rustc-hex v2.1.0
   Compiling rayon-core v1.7.1
   Compiling wasmparser v0.57.0
   Compiling rustc-hash v1.1.0
   Compiling gimli v0.22.0
   Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.16
   Compiling anyhow v1.0.32
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling arrayvec v0.4.12
   Compiling failure_derive v0.1.8
   Compiling parity-util-mem v0.7.0
   Compiling sp-std v2.0.0
   Compiling version_check v0.9.2
   Compiling parity-wasm v0.41.0
   Compiling ansi_term v0.12.1
   Compiling hash-db v0.15.2
   Compiling memory_units v0.3.0
   Compiling nodrop v0.1.14
   Compiling tiny-keccak v2.0.2
   Compiling environmental v1.1.1
   Compiling dyn-clone v1.0.2
   Compiling unicode-segmentation v1.6.0
   Compiling base58 v0.1.0
   Compiling hex v0.4.2
   Compiling bytes v0.5.6
   Compiling fixedbitset v0.2.0
   Compiling remove_dir_all v0.5.3
   Compiling multimap v0.8.1
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-shared v0.2.65
   Compiling bumpalo v3.4.0
   Compiling untrusted v0.7.1
   Compiling spin v0.5.2
   Compiling wasm-bindgen v0.2.65
   Compiling matches v0.1.8
   Compiling integer-sqrt v0.1.3
   Compiling send_wrapper v0.4.0
   Compiling percent-encoding v2.1.0
   Compiling unsigned-varint v0.3.3
   Compiling autocfg v0.1.7
   Compiling data-encoding v2.2.1
   Compiling void v1.0.2
   Compiling bs58 v0.3.1
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.1.7
   Compiling base64 v0.12.3
   Compiling quick-error v1.2.3
   Compiling httparse v1.3.4
   Compiling glob v0.3.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.2.1
   Compiling cache-padded v1.1.1
   Compiling scoped-tls v1.0.0
   Compiling fastrand v1.3.3
   Compiling waker-fn v1.0.0
   Compiling event-listener v2.2.1
   Compiling parking v1.0.6
   Compiling arc-swap v0.4.7
   Compiling atomic-waker v1.0.0
   Compiling async-task v3.0.0
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.18
   Compiling cranelift-codegen-shared v0.66.0
   Compiling stable_deref_trait v1.2.0
   Compiling try-lock v0.2.3
   Compiling target-lexicon v0.10.0
   Compiling prometheus v0.10.0
   Compiling fallible-iterator v0.2.0
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
   Compiling cpuid-bool v0.1.2
   Compiling c_linked_list v1.1.1
   Compiling nohash-hasher v0.2.0
   Compiling byteorder v0.5.3
   Compiling tower-service v0.3.0
   Compiling parity-send-wrapper v0.1.0
   Compiling ipnet v2.3.0
   Compiling lru_time_cache v0.10.0
   Compiling hex_fmt v0.3.0
   Compiling base64 v0.11.0
   Compiling atomic v0.4.6
   Compiling termcolor v1.1.0
   Compiling wasmparser v0.59.0
   Compiling wasmtime-environ v0.19.0
   Compiling more-asserts v0.2.1
   Compiling slog v2.5.2
   Compiling object v0.19.0
   Compiling rand_core v0.4.2
   Compiling leb128 v0.2.4
   Compiling take_mut v0.2.2
   Compiling hex-literal v0.3.1
   Compiling bitmask v0.5.0
   Compiling linked-hash-map v0.5.3
   Compiling unicode-width v0.1.8
   Compiling ansi_term v0.11.0
   Compiling bindgen v0.54.0
   Compiling rawpointer v0.2.1
   Compiling strsim v0.8.0
   Compiling vec_map v0.8.2
   Compiling peeking_take_while v0.1.2
   Compiling percent-encoding v1.0.1
   Compiling futures-timer v2.0.2
   Compiling shlex v0.1.1
   Compiling lazycell v1.2.1
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling ip_network v0.3.4
   Compiling scopeguard v0.3.3
   Compiling mio-named-pipes v0.1.7
   Compiling openssl-probe v0.1.2
   Compiling futures-core-preview v0.3.0-alpha.19
   Compiling retain_mut v0.1.1
   Compiling names v0.11.0
   Compiling nix v0.17.0
   Compiling sc-consensus-slots v0.8.0
   Compiling substrate-wasm-builder-runner v2.0.0
   Compiling platforms v0.2.1
   Compiling safe-mix v1.0.1
   Compiling instant v0.1.7
   Compiling hashbrown v0.8.1
   Compiling indexmap v1.5.0
   Compiling crossbeam-utils v0.7.2
   Compiling memoffset v0.5.5
   Compiling crossbeam-epoch v0.8.2
   Compiling num-traits v0.2.12
   Compiling num-integer v0.1.43
   Compiling rayon v1.3.1
   Compiling num-bigint v0.2.6
   Compiling num-rational v0.2.4
   Compiling num-complex v0.2.4
   Compiling lock_api v0.3.4
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.1
   Compiling thread_local v1.0.1
   Compiling tracing-core v0.1.16
   Compiling sharded-slab v0.0.9
   Compiling futures-channel v0.3.5
   Compiling tokio-service v0.1.0
   Compiling paste-impl v0.1.18
   Compiling block-padding v0.1.5
   Compiling unicode-normalization v0.1.13
   Compiling blake2s_simd v0.5.10
   Compiling blake2b_simd v0.5.10
   Compiling ed25519 v1.0.1
   Compiling miniz_oxide v0.4.0
   Compiling bitvec v0.17.4
   Compiling semver v0.9.0
   Compiling itertools v0.8.2
   Compiling itertools v0.9.0
   Compiling addr2line v0.13.0
   Compiling tokio-sync v0.1.8
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.3
   Compiling nom v5.1.2
   Compiling unicase v2.6.0
   Compiling proc-macro-error-attr v1.0.3
   Compiling proc-macro-error v1.0.3
   Compiling trie-root v0.16.0
   Compiling wasmi-validation v0.3.0
   Compiling heck v0.3.1
   Compiling http v0.2.1
   Compiling unicode-bidi v0.3.4
   Compiling hashbrown v0.6.3
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.1.1
   Compiling rand_pcg v0.1.2
   Compiling rand v0.6.5
   Compiling quicksink v0.1.2
   Compiling humantime v1.3.0
   Compiling clang-sys v0.29.3
   Compiling concurrent-queue v1.1.2
   Compiling owning_ref v0.4.1
   Compiling rand_core v0.3.1
   Compiling rand_jitter v0.1.4
   Compiling wast v21.0.0
   Compiling linked_hash_set v0.1.4
   Compiling textwrap v0.11.0
   Compiling matrixmultiply v0.2.3
   Compiling lock_api v0.1.5
   Compiling futures-channel-preview v0.3.0-alpha.19
   Compiling node-template-runtime v2.0.0 (/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime)
   Compiling substrate-build-script-utils v2.0.0
   Compiling paste v0.1.18
   Compiling rustc_version v0.2.3
   Compiling idna v0.2.0
   Compiling idna v0.1.5
   Compiling http-body v0.3.1
   Compiling async-channel v1.1.1
   Compiling rand_xorshift v0.1.1
   Compiling rand_isaac v0.1.1
   Compiling rand_hc v0.1.0
   Compiling futures-util-preview v0.3.0-alpha.19
   Compiling node-template v2.0.0 (/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/node)
   Compiling wat v1.0.22
   Compiling quote v1.0.7
   Compiling num_cpus v1.13.0
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.7.2
   Compiling time v0.1.43
   Compiling iovec v0.1.4
   Compiling net2 v0.2.34
   Compiling socket2 v0.3.12
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.8.0
   Compiling signal-hook-registry v1.2.0
   Compiling rand v0.4.6
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling get_if_addrs v0.5.3
   Compiling dirs-sys v0.3.5
   Compiling errno v0.2.6
   Compiling rand_os v0.1.3
   Compiling rand v0.5.6
   Compiling memmap v0.7.0
   Compiling fs-swap v0.2.4
   Compiling fdlimit v0.2.0
   Compiling rpassword v4.0.5
   Compiling jobserver v0.1.21
   Compiling which v3.1.1
   Compiling tracing-log v0.1.1
   Compiling kv-log-macro v1.0.7
   Compiling regalloc v0.0.27
   Compiling want v0.3.0
   Compiling want v0.2.0
   Compiling aho-corasick v0.7.13
   Compiling futures-lite v0.1.10
   Compiling bstr v0.2.13
   Compiling regex-automata v0.1.9
   Compiling dns-parser v0.8.0
   Compiling pwasm-utils v0.14.0
   Compiling hashbrown v0.1.8
   Compiling smallvec v0.6.13
   Compiling uint v0.8.3
   Compiling hash256-std-hasher v0.15.2
   Compiling generic-array v0.12.3
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.6.2
   Compiling parking_lot v0.9.0
   Compiling snow v0.7.1
   Compiling hyper v0.12.35
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.4.0
   Compiling blake2-rfc v0.2.18
   Compiling url v2.1.1
   Compiling url v1.7.2
   Compiling region v2.2.0
   Compiling tokio-sync v0.2.0-alpha.6
   Compiling futures-cpupool v0.1.8
   Compiling threadpool v1.8.1
   Compiling parking_lot v0.10.2
   Compiling rand_core v0.5.1
   Compiling bytes v0.4.12
   Compiling mio v0.6.22
   Compiling miow v0.3.5
   Compiling parking_lot v0.11.0
   Compiling rand v0.3.23
   Compiling clap v2.33.1
   Compiling directories v2.0.2
   Compiling statrs v0.10.0
   Compiling cc v1.0.58
   Compiling const-random-macro v0.1.8
   Compiling prost-build v0.6.1
   Compiling trie-db v0.22.1
   Compiling lru v0.6.0
   Compiling crossbeam-queue v0.2.3
   Compiling tokio-executor v0.1.10
   Compiling regex v1.3.9
   Compiling matchers v0.0.1
   Compiling digest v0.8.1
   Compiling block-buffer v0.7.3
   Compiling crypto-mac v0.7.0
   Compiling stream-cipher v0.3.2
   Compiling approx v0.3.2
   Compiling universal-hash v0.4.0
   Compiling block-cipher v0.7.1
   Compiling stream-cipher v0.4.1
   Compiling aead v0.3.2
   Compiling digest v0.9.0
   Compiling crypto-mac v0.8.0
   Compiling block-buffer v0.9.0
   Compiling cexpr v0.4.0
   Compiling tokio-executor v0.2.0-alpha.6
   Compiling once_cell v1.4.0
   Compiling parity-db v0.1.2
   Compiling synstructure v0.12.4
   Compiling wasm-bindgen-backend v0.2.65
   Compiling syn-mid v0.5.0
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.2.2
   Compiling rand_pcg v0.2.1
   Compiling tokio-io v0.1.13
   Compiling http v0.1.21
   Compiling string v0.2.1
   Compiling tokio-buf v0.1.1
   Compiling mio-uds v0.6.8
   Compiling mio-extras v2.0.6
   Compiling futures-macro v0.3.5
   Compiling tracing-attributes v0.1.11
   Compiling impl-trait-for-tuples v0.1.3
   Compiling ref-cast-impl v1.0.2
   Compiling sp-debug-derive v2.0.0
   Compiling derive_more v0.99.9
   Compiling dyn-clonable-impl v0.9.0
   Compiling prost-derive v0.6.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v2.0.0 (/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-3751beb66a2e85ab/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stderr
      Updating crates.io index
     Compiling libc v0.2.83
     Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
     Compiling getrandom v0.2.2
     Compiling serde v1.0.123
     Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.24
     Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.1
     Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
     Compiling syn v1.0.60
     Compiling ryu v1.0.5
     Compiling log v0.4.14
     Compiling serde_derive v1.0.123
     Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.10
     Compiling serde_json v1.0.61
     Compiling itoa v0.4.7
     Compiling byteorder v1.4.2
     Compiling same-file v1.0.6
     Compiling remove_dir_all v0.5.3
     Compiling either v1.6.1
     Compiling rustc-demangle v0.1.18
     Compiling ansi_term v0.12.1
     Compiling semver v0.6.0
     Compiling parity-wasm v0.32.0
     Compiling walkdir v2.3.1
     Compiling itertools v0.8.2
     Compiling build-helper v0.1.1
     Compiling fs2 v0.4.3
     Compiling atty v0.2.14
     Compiling semver v0.9.0
     Compiling toml v0.5.8
     Compiling quote v1.0.8
     Compiling wasm-gc-api v0.1.11
     Compiling rand_core v0.6.1
     Compiling rand_chacha v0.3.0
     Compiling rand v0.8.3
     Compiling cargo_metadata v0.10.0
     Compiling tempfile v3.2.0
     Compiling substrate-wasm-builder v2.0.1
     Compiling wasm-build-runner-impl v1.0.0 (/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild-runner/node-template-runtime5496440452611791206)
      Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 3m 19s
       Running `/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild-runner/node-template-runtime5496440452611791206/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/wasm-build-runner-impl`
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Copying `/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/Cargo.lock` to `/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/Dev/Rust/Zaryn/Substrate/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/Cargo.lock` can not fail; qed', /home/bashlord/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/substrate-wasm-builder-2.0.1/src/lib.rs:215:33
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
make: *** [Makefile:19: build] Error 101
```

Comment: The last error is a file copy issue - is suggests possible permissions issues on your filesystem. Check the mounted drive for those first?